# Use .contains with multiple words

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good day, How can I get to use contain with multiple words?

```
 String word = "word"

 answer1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (edittext.getText().toString().contains(word)){
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

That is the code if only a single word, in multiple words I use this:

```
     final String[] stringToCheck = new String[]{"word", "life"};
    for (final String s : stringToCheck)
  answer1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (answer1.getText().toString().contains(s)){
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if i remove the line *`for`* there is an error.

but that code doesn't fit in my case, because i am using this layout many times.
So is there an alternative way or simple way to use contain method in multiple word without using stringarray?
Or Can i insert stringarray on another string array? (because i think this will solve my problem)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
             public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                String answer = answer1.getText().toString();

                for (String s : stringToCheck) {
                    if (answer.contains(s)) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing when adding that for loop is overwrite the `OnKeyListener` multiple times.
What you could do is the following:

```
final String[] stringToCheck = new String[]{"word", "life"};
final Stream<String> wordsStream = Stream.of(stringToCheck);

  answer1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if (wordsStream.anyMatch(s -> answer1.getText().toString().contains(s))) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This would check all the words in the stream against the answer and as soon as any of them match it will trigger the Toast.

Should you need to make them all match at once then you can replace Stream::anyMatch with Stream::allMatch